# Как создать файл на android через приложение на python

Tags: python, android, kivy

Пишу игру на android на python на kivy. Дошел до момента реализации сохранения и дело встало. Элементарно папку не получается создать через приложение, оно закрывается. Несколько дней уже ищу в интернете. Про это вообще информации никакой. Только единожды попался на форуме вопрос похожий, но решения рабочего так и не нашлось. На данный момент создал тестовое простейшее приложение для создания папки на android которое при нажатии на кнопку вылетает.

Тестовый .apk

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import os
import json

#Window.size = (960, 540)
Window.fullscreen = True

class WindowOne(Screen):
    def SAVE(self):       
        
        if not os.path.isdir("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/folder"):
            os.mkdir("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/folder")   
       
class SaveApp(App):

    def build(self):
        
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(WindowOne())
        
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SaveApp().run()
```

Файл .kv

```
<WindowOne>:
    lab: lab
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            on_press:
                root.SAVE()
        
        Label:
            id: lab
```

Единственная информация которую нашел в интернете:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

С этими строками приложение сразу вылетает.

Пробовал вставить в  .spec   buildozer

```
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Не помогло

Comment: ну так надо читать логи и узнавать причину крэша

Comment: @Эникейщик   Как можно посмотреть логи на телефоне?

Comment: Я уверен, что любой поиск выдаст вам достаточно результатов на такой запрос с подробными инструкциями. Вкратце - так же, как и на эмуляторе.

Comment: разрешение на работу с файлами у приложения есть?

Comment: Поймайте исключение через `try-except`, да выведите его на экран, например, ну или ещё куда-нибудь. А вообще про отсутствие разрешения хорошая мысль.

Comment: @Эникейщик это как раз таки единственная инфа которую нашел в интернете. Сейчас дополнил информацию по вопросу - вставил еще код. Это я так понимаю как раз разрешение